# Create a thread and wait for actions in C#

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code which generates customers in a while loop:

```
Queue queue = new Queue();
while (continueGenerating)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        queue.DoSmth(customer);
    }
```

and a class Queue:

```
public class Queue
    {
        public void DoSmth(Customer customer) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New customer");
        }
    }
```

The problem is this: I need to have a thread which is created earlier in the program and waits until a new customer is generated. Only after the customer is generated the function `queue.DoSmth(customer)` is called.

I know that it may be solved with an event and event handler but I don't understand how it should work with threads.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Using `async` and `Task`s may be what you need. You could make a function that returns a Task which creates a customer and then calls `DoSmth`. You could then use `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep` to use CPU more efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simplified version of something that I have used for situations like this for scheduling actions to happen on a single background thread

```cs
class BackgroundThread
{
    private readonly _queue = new BlockingCollection();
    private Thread _backgroundThread;

    public BackgroundThread() : IDisposable
    {
        _backgroundThread = new Thread(run)
        {
            IsBackground = true
        };
        _thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public Task Enqueue(Action action)
    {
        var task = new Task(action);
        _queue.Add(task);
        return task;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _queue.CompleteAdding();
        _thread.Join();
    }

    private void run()
    {
        foreach (var task in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            task.RunSynchonously();
        }
    }
}
```

so then in your case you would use it something like this

```cs
using (var bt = new BackgroundThread)
{
    while (continueGenerating)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        bt.Enqueue(() => { queue.DoSmth(customer); });
    }
}
```

In this case I'm not using the returned task from Enqueue, but you could use the task to `Wait` or `await` the task or catch/handle exceptions or cancel.